# Why do I get a "not a function" error for my function?

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I have been building this Accordion component for a few days, and I have run into an issue whose solution has eluded me.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import './CbdsAccordion.scss';

const CbdsAccordion = ({
  items,
  multiple = false
}) => {

  const [active, setActive] = useState(0);
  const [visibility, setVisibility] = useState(false);

  const isActive = () => (multiple ? visibility : active);

  const toggleVisibility = ({onToggle}) => {
    setVisibility((visible) => !visible);
    onToggle();
  };

  return (
    <div className='cbds-c-accordion'>

      {items.map((item, index) => (
        <div className={`card ${isActive() ? "accordion-active" : ""}`}
          key={index}
          active={active === index}
          multiple={multiple}
          onToggle={() => setActive((active => active === index ? '' : index))}
        >
          <div className='card-header' onClick={toggleVisibility}>
            {item.accordionLabel}
            <span className='accordion-icon'>+</span>
          </div>
          <div className='card-body'>
            {item.accordionPanel}
          </div>
        </div>
      )
      )}
    </div>
  )
}


CbdsAccordion.propTypes = {
  multiple: PropTypes.bool,
  active: PropTypes.bool
};

CbdsAccordion.defaultProps = {
  multiple: false,
  active: false
};

export default CbdsAccordion
```

I've tried including the 'onToggle' function in the props at the beginning of my component, in the default props at the end of my component, and inside of the .map props. Each time I try to use it, I get an error telling me it's not a function, or a code hint that tells me its value is declared but never used. Can someone please shed some light for me? Thank you.

Comment: `((active` you're missing the closing parenthesis here I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the divs inside the map as a component, but they're just divs, thus, they don't have such "onToggle", "multiple" or "active" props.

I suggest you to abstract all the HTML inside the map into another component which actually receives that props and use it as they're supposed to.

Then, use the new component to handle the behaviour of the accordion item.

The content inside the map should look something like:

```js
    <AccordionItem 
      key={`accordion-item-${index}`} 
      onToggle={() => setActive((active) => active === index ? '' : index)} 
      active={active === index} 
      multiple={multiple} 
    />
```

By the way, it's not a good practice to use an index as a map key. If you have multiple maps, you could be generating multiple items with a same key. The keys should be unique in the whole page.